# Suddenly Can't click any buttons in asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, mouse

I have a very strange problem with an asp.net webforms web application. As of today, I suddenly can't click any more buttons after I've logged into the site. On the login page everything works as usual, but on the page afterwards the cursor no longer changes into a pointer and clicking has no effect. With the keyboard I can easily navigate and also press the buttons.

I've already tried restarting the PC, swapping the mouse, and tried a different browser.

Everything works as usual on other websites, as well as on the published version of the same asp.net web application.

I am completely at a loss...

Any ideas?

Here is the screenshot of an unfinished request I found with the help of @Baskovli

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason can be that some request that does not completed and page waits for result if request is not async.
Other one can be a function in frond end which all the time makes request to server without stopping, a loop without ending.
Did you monitored the Network on DevTools?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I just checked it and there is pending unfinished request with status code 101 'switching protocols' and I have no idea what that means and what I can do about it.

Comment: You are welcome. Post a screenshot with the unfiinished request in order to investigate it.